# Optimize function while parameters sum to 1

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to optimize a function, while forcing the sum of the parameters to equal 1. I've tried to understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124898/using-optim-to-find-minimization-while-also-forcing-the-parameters-to-sum-to-1), but it seems that it's evolved into something more complicated than the initial question. Hopefully a simpler example might benefit me and others as well:

```
library(compositions)    
fun <- function(x){
      x <- clo(c(x[1],x[2]),total=1)
      y <- x[1]^2 - x[2]^2 + x[1]*x[2] + 2*x[1] - 2*x[2]
      print(y)
    }

    optim1 <- optim(c(1/2,1/2), fun, lower=c(0,0), method = "L-BFGS-B")

    fun(x=optim1$par)
```

Is this a viable way to perform an optimization with constraints where the sum of  parameters = 1? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example---a little data to test on? And where is the `clo()` function from?

Comment: And, why not just have `x[2] = 1 - x[1]` and do univariate optimization on `x[1]`?

Comment: Edited the post to include the package

Comment: Would you be able to edit the function such that univariate optimization isn't applicable? The actual problem I'm trying to solve requires three parameters.

Comment: Do you want to maximize or to minimize ? The minimum is minus infinity.

Comment: @EricFrey for any `n` parameters you can define `x[n] = 1 - sum(x[1:(n - 1)])`, optimize with `n - 1` parameters and calculate thte last one.

Comment: You can use the `Rsolnp` package to include an equality constraint.

Comment: @Gregor If you do `x3 = 1-x1-x2` what bounds do you take on `x1` and `x2` ?

Comment: Ah, didn't read closely enough - didn't notice the bounds.